# Animation node get particle system points around a radius

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to this one:
[image]

As far my result:

[image]

My workflow is to create a spline using a particle system. The problem is that I want to use just points inside a radius i.e. for each point in the particle system, loop and create splines only with points with a distance less than, let's say, 10
This is my node system

[image]

I was thinking about using a script node, but the documentation for animation nodes it's not really clear about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender StackExchange! The *Find Close Points* node can be used here:

[image: Node Tree]

The max distance option defines the proximity of points as you want. This example is actually included in the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/mesh/operators/find_close_points.html):

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about this node :) thank you. I was thinking about a script node, and to write some python code, but this is way more simple

Comment: @Rage By the way, can you tell me what is not clear in the documentation so that we can improve it?

Comment: My idea was to create a simple script in python, getting the particles coordinates from the particle system and then create splines. I've seen there's a node for this, the invoke program node, but, in my opinion, it's not very clear how to use it for python scripting. In specific, in the documentation many examples are shown, but how do you exactly get the variables in python code from the invoke subprogram node? Anyways, I think we're going out of the topic, if you want to we could continue discuss it somewhere else (I'd like to)

Comment: @Rage Sure, where do you want to continue this? The invoke node only invokes the the subprogram, to define the subprogram, you need to use the script node, the documentation for the script node is available [here](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/script.html).